# Count specific divs in html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a hidden input that should get the value of counted divs

```
<div class="items">
    <div class="item">
       
    </div>
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="items" value="" />
```

i have tried this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="items" value="$('.item').length" />
```

but of course it doesn't work.
How to get that length?
How to count the divs with class item?

#### update

i have a dynamic form with option to add new divs so i need to count them because i use that value later in backend

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, do you want to populate that after you submit a form? Dynamic?

Comment: Sidenote: From a semantic point of view, `items` should probably be an `ul` or `ol`, and `.item`should be a `li`.

Comment: Ok, so `requestAnimationFrame(function animate() {$('input[name="items"]').val($('.item').length); requestAnimationFrame(animate);});`

Comment: 2nd sidenote: This is a perfect use-case for an MVC or MVVM library like [tag:knockout.js].

Comment: Why the down votes??

Comment: you question wasn't clear, you asked a question, got replies then you had other demands.

Comment: But @RoryMcCrossan has answered it perfectly and all is fine....he understood it clearly...what other demands did i have?

Comment: so did I, you had on submit then dynamiclly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix this by running your code when the page loads:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('input[name="items"]').val($('.item').length);
  }); 
</script>
```

Given your update it sounds like you instead need to run the code when your `form` element is submit. You can use the following code to do that:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $(document)on('submit', '#myForm', function() {
      $('input[name="items"]').val($('.item').length);
    }); 
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes - although it would need to go in a `submit` handler of your form, which would be inside the document.ready handler unless you place your `<script>` just before the `</body>`

Comment: No problem, glad to help